Create connected drop-downs in google sheets where value can be present only in one drop-down
It's easier to explain my problem using this sample sheet.

I have 3 rooms with 3 seats in each room. I also have a list of people who can be placed at seats. The problem is I can put the same person on two or more seats. The desired behavior is when I select the same person for the second time on another seat it should be removed from his previous seat automatically, so this way it will be impossible to duplicate persons.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Using Nested For Loops to Remove the First Duplicate Value
The script uses nested for loops to check the range for matching values, with the first loop iterating through the rows and the second through the columns. Then it clears the first duplicate while keeping the second occurrence/updated value.
Below is the full code:
const onEdit = (e) => {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = e.range;
  var vl = rg.getValue();
  var row = rg.getRow();
  var col = rg.getColumn();
  if (vl && (col == 2 || col == 3 || col == 4)) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      for (let j = 2; j <= 4; j++) {
        var srg = sh.getRange(i, j);
        if (!(i == row && j == col) && vl == srg.getValue()) {
          srg.setValue("");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Expected value
Paste the script and test it by updating the spreadsheet.
Before:




Room 1
Room 2
Room 3




Seat 1





Seat 2

Josh



Seat 3

Josh (updated value)




After:




Room 1
Room 2
Room 3




Seat 1





Seat 2





Seat 3

Josh





References

JavaScript for Loop
Spreadsheet Service


Try something like this:
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast(`entree: e.value = ${e.value}`)
  const sh =  e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.rowStart >1 && e.range.rowStart < 5 && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart <5 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast(`gate1 e.value = ${e.value}`)
    let seated = sh.getRange(2,2,3,3).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
    let same = [... new Set(seated)].length == seated.length; Checks for duplicates
    if(seated  && !same){
      e.range.setValue("");
      e.source.toast(`gate2: allready seated`)
    }
  }
}

It assumes thet the one just added is the duplicate but I suppose with more testing you may find this inadequate
